# Modifying Patch Creation Properties (.pcp) file programmatically?

Tags: windows-installer, patch, orca

Is there a way to script the complete process of a hotfix build using msiexec.exe and msimsp.exe with a Patch Creation Properties file?

I use msiexec.exe to create network installations of the before and after msi files, Orca to create a .pcp file, and msimsp.exe to create the patch file.

I have been following the steps in these two articles:

[How to create installation patches for VS.NET deployment projects](http://69.10.233.10/KB/install/dotnetpatching.aspx)

[Patching and Updates](http://parmeshwar.blogsome.com/2005/08/01/patching-and-updates-2/)

Suppose I had created a patch from 1.0 to 1.1 and now want to create a patch from 1.1 to 1.2 (or 1.0 to 1.2). I would like to reuse the .pcp file I created with Orca, but any modifications to that file should be done through scripting (e.g. VBScript) rather than someone having to open it in Orca again. From what I understand, I have to - at the very least - change the PatchGUID value.

How do I make such a modification using scripting?

Answer (score 1):

Why not the WIX way:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/patch_building.htm